# How to expand AppBarLayout/Toolbar everytime fragment destination changes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am building single activity app with a lot of fragments and I am using Jetpack navigation component. I have `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` in Toolbar so that when the user scrolls content Toolbar will be scroll-able to give much space and it works just fine.
But in one fragment I have **SearchView** in **Action Bar menu** so when the user navigate to this search Fragment from fragment which had scroll-able content the SearchView and other menu items will be automatically hidden.
How to make ActionBar/Toolbar visible when each fragment is created/Shown.

My Activity Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.activities.MainActivity">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_nav">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/main_bottom" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Example of my Fragment layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.fragments.notification.NotificationsFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was simple. I solved it by adding listener on NavController

```
        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, _, _ ->
            appBarLayout.setExpanded(true, true)
        }
```